# Determine length of days between two dates and display as number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to get the number of days between these two days shown in a separate column called "Days" I tried using the DATEDIFF function but could not seem to get that to work. Any suggestions? the query works fine otherwise to accomplish all my other needs.

```
SELECT          
    Orders.OrderID,
    Customers.CompanyName,
    (OrderDetails.Quantity * OrderDetails.UnitPrice) AS OrderCost,
    FORMAT(Orders.ShippedDate, 'MMM dd yyyy') AS ShippedDate
FROM
    Customers 
INNER JOIN
    Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
INNER JOIN
    OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
WHERE 
    ShippedDate >= '1994-01-01' AND ShippedDate <= '1994-01-31' 
ORDER BY 
    Orders.OrderID, CompanyName, ShippedDate, Orders.OrderDate
```

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

And here is my current result from the query:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please see edited post. Hopefully, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the select clause ... `DATEDIFF(DAY, ShippedDate, Orders.OrderDate)` AS days

Comment: Brilliant. That is all it took. Thanks! I was just missing the DAY part inside the brackets actually.